# How to translate custom values for all indexes of array based form input fields for validation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, localization, laravel-6

Take this array based form input fields that allows user to add and remove items with type (simple or complex) and complex infos:

```html
<div class="item">
    <div>
        <h2>Type</h2>
        <label><input type="radio" name="data[0][type]" value="simple"> Simple ABC stuff</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="data[0][type]" value="complex"> Complex XYZ stuff</label>
    </div>
    <div class="complex"> <!-- it will be visible only when type is "Complex XYZ stuff" -->
        <h2>Complex info</h2>
        <input type="text" name="data[0][complex_info]"/>
    </div>
    <button class="remove">Remove item</button>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div>
        <h2>Type</h2>
        <label><input type="radio" name="data[1][type]" value="simple"> Simple ABC stuff</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="data[1][type]" value="complex"> Complex XYZ stuff</label>
    </div>
    <div class="complex"> <!-- it will be visible only when type is "Complex XYZ stuff" -->
        <h2>Complex info</h2>
        <input type="text" name="data[1][complex_info]"/>
    </div>
    <button class="remove">Remove item</button>
</div>
<button class="add">Add item</button>
```

When user selects the "Complex XYZ stuff" type, then "Complex info" input should be required. So we set this form request rule in Laravel 6.x:

```php
public function rules() {
    return ['data.*.complex_info' => 'required_if:data.*.type,complex'];
}
```

When the `required_if` validation rule fails, we get the error message `The :attribute field is required when :other is :value.` that with the filled parameters should result in a message like this: `The Complex info field is required when Type is Complex XYZ stuff.` (expected message).

The following `validation.php` language file would work for a form of 2 items:

```php
return [

    /* ... */

    'values' => [
        'data' => [
            0 => [
                'type' => [
                    'simple' => 'Simple ABC stuff',
                    'complex' => 'Complex XYZ stuff',
                ]
            ],
            1 => [
                'type' => [
                    'simple' => 'Simple ABC stuff',
                    'complex' => 'Complex XYZ stuff',
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ]
];
```

And I need it to work for a form with an indefinite number of items (all indexes), so I thought about using the `*` wildcard like:

```php
return [

    /* ... */

    'values' => [
        'data' => [
            '*' => [
                'type' => [
                    'simple' => 'Simple ABC stuff',
                    'complex' => 'Complex XYZ stuff',
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ]
];
```

But it doesn't work, the `:value` parameter of the `required_if` validation rule's error message is not properly translated: `The Complex info field is required when Type is complex.` (actual message).

Comment: From what I see on the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/402ca919344c25c67b487a12e4a8b6edb0cdfc57/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/FormatsMessages.php#L316-L340) it is literally doing `0`, `1`, `2`, etc., so I think there is no solution in this case. And the same code is being applied for Laravel 7 and 8, so no one "fixed" or took care of this (if I am not reading wrongly)... If you have `xdebug` installed on your machine, try putting a breakpoint in that source file on line `325` and check what is really doing. Maybe it is fixable.

Comment: If it is not, I could try to "fix it" but that would be on next release for 8.x+ or maybe 9.x an on...